# Error staring EJB3 service JBOSS, org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0

Tags: deployment, jboss, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

I had an EJB3 that is using an EJB2 interfaces and it's deploying fine on my local dev instance. However, trying to deploy it on one of the servers at work I get the following exception below.

**[org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.j2ee:ear=myear.ear,jar=myejb.jar,name=myejb,service=EJB3_IORFactory state=Create
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
        at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidNameHelper.read(InvalidNameHelper.java:60)
        at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextExtStub.to_name(_NamingContextExtStub.java:86)**

Although I'm seeing that when I open the jmx-console I can see that the EJB is deployed and and all the operations inside are working. Any ideas on what might cause that?

I'm using JBossEAP 5.1.1

Comment: Looks like you might be missing a library or some other dependency on the server.

Comment: I guess not, at least it would come with something more obvious if a library is missing.